# call form from project added as refrence to other one

Tags: c#, .net

i have 2 projects when the user Click on a button in the first project 
he suppose to see the form which in the Second Project ??
i am using C#

Comment: You should fix your title as you already have the reference set up and now you want to no an additional thing.

Answer (score 0):

A form is just a class like any other

```
Library.FormClass F = new Library.FormClass()
F.Show();
```

Comment: Error 2 The type or namespace name 'WinUI' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\omnia\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Report\Report\Form1.cs 21 37 Report                             i had this error

Comment: you need to use the fully qualified class name.   you can use the object explorer to find the full name.

Answer (score 0):

Your Second Project must be compiled with the output type of `Class Library`. Then get a reference of the dll of your second project to your first project.

You can access a form (or controls, etc..) from your second project by creating a new object of that form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    SecondProject.Form1 f1 = new SecondProject.Form1()
    f1.Show();
}
```